# Backgroundtask Android Java, permanent every X seconds

Tags: java, android, background

Until now I have always used the "AlertManager" for background tasks. This no longer works as it should on new Android versions. It must be started every 15 seconds and must not be stopped by the system under any circumstances. When the phone is restarted, the background tasks must also start. Now the background tasks only start once, then nothing more happened.

Is there a solution?

That's how I planned my tasks:

**MainActivity.java**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, hintergrundModus.class);
PendingIntent startServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0,startServiceIntent,0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
if(alarmManager != null)
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,hintergrundModus.timeHintergrundmodus,startServicePendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Android, you'll need to replace deprecated usages of `IntentService` with `androidx.core.app.JobIntentService`. (And don't forget to remove the implementation of `IntentService#onBind(Intent)`, or your service will never start)

```java
class hintergrundModus extends IntentService

    @Override
    protected IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) { 
        return null
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {    
        ...
    }
}
```

will become

```java
import androidx.core.app.JobIntentService;

class hintergrundModus extends JobIntentService {

    @Override
    public void onHandleWork(Intent arg0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

For the `AlarmManager`, you'll also no longer call your service directly using `PendingIntent#getService`, but will instead create an intermediary `BroadcastReceiver` that can then enqueue your work when called.

```java
import static androidx.core.app.JobIntentService.enqueueWork;

public class ServiceLaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String RECEIVER_KEY = "com.package.ACTION";
    public static final int UNIQUE_JOB_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVER_KEY)) {
            enqueueWork(context, hintergrundModus.class, UNIQUE_JOB_ID , intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Which can then be referenced by `PendingIntent#getBroadcast`

```java
Intent launcherReceiverIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceLaunchReceiver.class);
PendingIntent startServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, launcherReceiverIntent, 0);
```

You may also want to look into using `AlarmManager#setExact` or `AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` on devices running API 19 or higher, if the timing-precision for repetitions is required. You can then schedule the subsequent alarm after your work in the `JobIntentService` has completed, instead of scheduling a repeating alarm. From this note on `AlarmManager#set`:

> Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later.

You'll also find that newer versions of Android can be very aggressive when it comes to terminating background applications. Since your service appears to be short-lived, binding it to a foreground notification (via `startForeground(Int, Notification)`) may not work for you. In this case, you may need to request Battery Optimization exclusions from the user at runtime, in order to avoid the system limitations.

Lastly, in the `BroadcastReceiver` you use for listening to system boot notifications, implement the above code for enqueuing your new `JobIntentService`, or for scheduling the first alarm to defer it for later.